# mysql - extract multiple matches within a field

Tags: mysql, regex, preg-match, regexp-substr

I have a field with value :
`a:3:{i:0;s:3:"945";i:1;s:3:"946";i:2;s:3:"947";}`

Objective is to get the below output (basically all numbers sandwiched between double quotes):
`945`
`946`
`947`

Regex matches have a global matching which returns an array of multiple matches, is there a way to do this in MySQL ?

I tried the below :

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT 'a:3:{i:0;s:3:"945";i:1;s:3:"946";i:2;s:3:"947";}' AS input) T1
WHERE  T1.input REGEXP '(")[0-9]+(")';
```

The query needs to work on a single row only, need not run on full table.

Comment: You want 3 separate rows? If that's the case, this gets to be some REALLY nasty code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows (Have you considered postgres?)

Comment: This would be a [rather trivial task](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f3TVCFk3swTKfjTpe5oQBQ/0) with postgres.

Comment: yes 3 separate rows, in MySQL. I think I might have to make a stored procedure and pass the input string to it.. haven't been able to find any other solution.

Comment: Unserialize and do the task in your client.